# Regular expression (RegEx) not working

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that matches a String at the beginning of the input which satisfies following  conditions:

1. start with a letter
2. end with a letter or a number
3. may contain letters, numbers and spaces

I have this expression so far:

```
^([a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+)|[a-zA-Z]
```

http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp

The OR statement in the expression is to allow a String that consists of one letter.

The problem is that the second part of the OR statement is always preferred, so when the input is `query1`, it matches only `q`.

How can I solve this problem?

Is there a way to simplify the expression? My way seems a little to complex for this relatively simple case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^([a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$|^[a-zA-Z]$
```

You can make use of `^$` anchors to imply that that it is only for `single letter string`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to satisfy all conditions:

```
^[a-zA-Z](?:[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?$
```

- `^[a-zA-Z]` matches a letter at start.
- `(?:...)?` is optional part to allow single char input.
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]` in the makes sure last char is alpha-numeric.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uD9cW9/1)

Answer (score 0):

Regex to match with a character at the start, character, number or spaces in between and ends with character or number:

^[a-z|A-Z][a-z|A-Z|0-9| ]*[a-z|A-Z|0-9]$